# exception when mocking a unity container

Tags: c#, unity-container, moq, mstest

I am trying to mock a unity container - I using Moq and Getting this errror

```
System.ArgumentException: Invalid setup on a non-overridable member:
c => c.Resolve<ILogisticsAdapter>(new [] {})
```

Here is the code from the setup portion of my test.

```
 var mockContainer = new Mock<IUnityContainer>();
      mockContainer.Setup(c => c.Resolve<ILogisticsAdapter>()).Returns(logicsticsAdapter);
      IUnityContainer container = mockContainer.Object;
```

What am I missing? I am no master at mocks in general or unit testing but from what I can tell this should work...

Just in case it is important I am using VS2010 and MS Test...

Thanks

Here is the whole test fixture -you can see I have changed it to use a real unity container however ideally I don't want to create a real unity container - it isn't what I am testing. You can however see the code I commented out...

```
 [TestMethod]
public void WhenContructed_AdapterGetsSet()
{
  //Prepare
  ILogisticsAdapter logicsticsAdapter = new Mock<ILogisticsAdapter>().Object;
  var mockEventAggregator = new Mock<IEventAggregator>();
  mockEventAggregator.Setup(x => x.GetEvent<SetHelpMessageEvent>()).Returns(new SetHelpMessageEvent());
  IEventAggregator eventAggregator = mockEventAggregator.Object;
  IRegionManager regionManager = new Mock<IRegionManager>().Object;

  //var mockContainer = new Mock<IUnityContainer>();
  //mockContainer.Setup(c => c.Resolve<ILogisticsAdapter>(null)).Returns(logicsticsAdapter);
  //IUnityContainer container = mockContainer.Object;
  IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();
  container.RegisterInstance<ILogisticsAdapter>(logicsticsAdapter);
  container.RegisterInstance<IRegionManager>(regionManager);
  container.RegisterInstance<IEventAggregator>(eventAggregator);

  //Act
  var warehouseOrdersViewModel = new WarehouseOrdersViewModel_Accessor(container);
  Assert.IsNotNull(warehouseOrdersViewModel.logisticsAdapter);

}
```

Thanks!

Comment: It is usually a smell when you have to mock IoC container. Your classes shouldn't know about Unity.

Comment: Snowbear makes a good point.  In general, only your very top level code should be aware of the IoC container's existence.  Also: Since we don't know what's being resolved out of the container by the WarehouseOrdersViewModel_Accessor, it makes it hard to offer any more advice.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I strongly agree with the above commenters - you shouldn't (in most cases) be referencing the container anywhere other than the bootstrapper. In your case, it looks like you're implementing a view model locator type of class, so it might be ok. However, please think carefully about whether this is the right thing to do. Usually using explicit factories or getting Func injected by the container will get you the same place without coupling you explicitly to the container.

Having said that, if you're using Unity 2.0, take a good look at the IUnityContainer interface. You'll see the method you're trying to mock out isn't actually on the interface. It's an extension method. IUnityContainer actually only has one "native" resolve method:

```
object Resolve(Type t, string name, params ResolverOverride[] resolverOverrides);
```

So you'll need to mock *that* method specifically. The extension methods just do some parameter juggling and turn around and call the Resolve that's directly on the interface.

You might still run into issues - there's actually a bug in the .NET framework that causes problems when codegenning implementations of interfaces that have methods that return the interface as well, which the RegisterType, RegisterInstance, and, well every other method on IUnityContainer does. This is a problem with just about all the mocking frameworks I know of right now. If you *do* hit this, the only option would be a manual mock - write a class that implements IUnityContainer yourself rather than using the mock framework to do it.

Comment: +1 for answering the question and also pointing out the (potential) folly of non-bootstrapper code knowing about the container

Comment: OK - so I should be creating the constructor like this WarehouseOrdersViewModel(IRegionManager regionManager, IEventAggregator eventAggregator, IMyAdapter adapter) : base(regionManager, eventAggregator)???